# Unwanted plus sign in message generated from e-mail FORM?

Tags: html, forms, email

I have a an e-mail form on my website,

But when the message comes up in the new message window in the e-mail application plus (+) signs will appear instead of a blank space.

askhaksdasda+akjsdhaksdhasda+asjdaksdas

How do I fix this?

Comment: Most likely, you forgot to URL-unescape your inputs. Can you show us your code?

Comment: This looks like a server-side issue. Can we see the server-side code, or at least know the server-side language?

Comment: I actually fixed it with 

enctype="text/plain" 

<form method="POST" action="mailto:?Subject=Mina%20Anteckningar" enctype="text/plain">


inside of the form tag. But now I have problems with characters å,ä,ö that will be Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶ instead! How do I fix this?

Comment: This time, it seems as if the form was sent with UTF-8 (perfectly valid), but treated as ISO-Latin-1 or something in that sense.